# Use Different Locale for @NumberFormat in Spring

Tags: spring, locale, number-formatting

I am working on a Spring 3 project and I need to format a `Long` field for Turkish currency. The default `Locale` of the application is `en_US`. I used the `@NumberFormat` annotation as below:

```
@NumberFormat(style=NumberFormat.Style.CURRENCY)
public Long getBudgetLimit() {
    return budgetLimit; 
}
```

The annotation works and formats the form field in English locale. However I need to use Turkish locale for this field. Is there a way to set the locale of a single field or a page different than the application's locale?

*Edit*: I just found the answer myself. Use  a custom editor in the controller as below:

```
NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(new Locale("tr","TR"));
dataBinder.registerCustomEditor(Long.class, new CustomNumberEditor(Long.class,numberFormat, true));
```

and do not use the `@NumberFormat` annotation. For same reason it gave an error for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways but you could for example register a custom implementation of `AnnotationFormatterFactory<NumberFormat>` as a bean which would allow you to handle the formatting manually. This is [documentented in the Spring documentation section 6.6](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#format). The example in the documentation even handles the use case of adjusting `@NumberFormat`'s behavior.

Comment: Thank you, this is a more comprehensive and centralized (changing @NumberFormat's behavior throughout the application) solution.