# Spring MVC @NumberFormat(pattern = "#.###,##") Malformed pattern

Tags: java, spring, forms, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC (4.3.3.RELEASE). My Entity class has a BigDecimal field that I would like display in spring form:form

```
<form:input path="number" />
```

as 1.000.000,11

I tried @NumberFormat(pattern =  "#.###,##") on field but I have this exception:

org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull @org.springframework.format.annotation.NumberFormat java.math.BigDecimal to type java.lang.String for value '100000000000.22'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed pattern "#.###,##"

when I try to view the form.

My entity class is:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test")
public class Test {
private BigDecimal number;
...

@NumberFormat(pattern =  "#.###,##")
@Column(name="number")
public BigDecimal getNumber() {
    return number;
}
public void setNumber(BigDecimal number) {
    this.number = number;
}
...
}
```

Is there a method to view in form this pattern =  "#.###,##"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42056112/spring-mvc-controller-numberformat-annotation-pattern-issue-in-bigdecimal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved with:

```
public class BigDecimalEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BigDecimalEditor.class);

@Override
public String getAsText() {
    String s = null;
    if (getValue() != null) {
        BigDecimal bd = (BigDecimal) getValue();
        DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
        df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
        s = df.format(bd);
    }
    return s;
}

@Override
public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {
    DecimalFormat df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    df.setParseBigDecimal(true);
    BigDecimal bd = null;
    try {
        bd = (BigDecimal) df.parseObject(text);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        logger.error("setAsText error", e);
        setValue(null);
    }
    setValue(bd);
}
```

}

and in @Controller class

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(BigDecimal.class, new BigDecimalEditor());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe @NumberFormat only supports the English locale.  This post has a good answer for an alternative [Use Different Locale for @NumberFormat in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091086/use-different-locale-for-numberformat-in-spring)