# @NumberFormat form validation for European local w/ Swagger

Tags: java, spring-boot, number-formatting

I have a form which is a POJO for a Spring-Boot REST endpoint.

It looks like this:

```
@NumberFormat(style = NumberFormat.Style.DEFAULT, pattern = "##.###.###,##")
private Double floor_space;
```

when I fire up the app server in swagger and enter in the number: 55,57 swagger says it's not a number. I've also tried

```
style = NumberFormat.Style.CURRENCY
```

but that isn't working either.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the `style` attribute has no effect when `pattern` is specified, so you can't use both together:

> **Each attribute is mutually exclusive, so only set one attribute per
>   annotation instance** (the one most convenient one for your formatting
>   needs). **When the pattern() attribute is specified, it takes precedence
>   over the style() attribute**. When no annotation attributes are
>   specified, the default format applied is style-based for either number
>   of currency, depending on the annotated field or method parameter
>   type.
>
> *[Source](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.html)*

Next, as of my understanding of the docs the pattern seems to be a pattern as specified by [java.text.DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html).
DecimalFormat patterns always recognize `.` as decimal separator and `,` as grouping separator, which makes your pattern invalid:

```
.   Decimal separator or monetary decimal separator
,   Grouping separator
```

The decision, which character is the decimal separator in the string while parsing is done at runtime by the given [Locale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html).

Apparently it is not possible to adjust the Locale for the @NumberFormat annotation, so you have two options:

- Adjust your System/VM Locale. I **strongly advise against this**, since this affects all your code and may yield strange behaviour everwhere where code is defaulting to the default locale.
- or don't use the @NumberFormat annotation at all, as explained in this answer: [Use Different Locale for @NumberFormat in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091086/use-different-locale-for-numberformat-in-spring)

Comment: I've tried them both individually & together. 

what you're saying doesn't match the java docs for spring.[it says] (https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/NumberFormat.Style.html):

PERCENT
public static final NumberFormat.Style PERCENT
The percent format for the current locale.

Number format is there for a reason and it does pay attention to locales. one just has to use it properly. I don't know the right way. you're confusing it with decimal format.

Comment: If you have a look at the Spring source code, you'll see that 1. [it always chooses NumberStyleFormatter and ignores the `style` property, if a pattern is specified](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3a0f309e2c/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/number/NumberFormatAnnotationFormatterFactory.java#L60) and 2. [NumberStyleFormatter uses DecimalFormat to do the actuall formatting](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/3a0f309e2c/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/number/NumberStyleFormatter.java#L80)

Comment: sadly that's still not solving my swagger problem. and it doesn't let my FE guy wire in the 55,75 formats he's getting into my REST endpoint either.